# data stored as a backslash in javascript console

Tags: javascript, json

This is my JS code

```js
add = document.getElementById("add");
add.addEventListener("click", () => {
  console.log("Updating List...");
  tit = document.getElementById("title").value;
  desc = document.getElementById("description").value;
  if (localStorage.getItem("itemsJson") == null) {
    itemJsonArray = [];
    itemJsonArray.push([tit, desc]);
    localStorage.setItem("itemsJson", JSON.stringify(itemJsonArray));
  }
});
```

[image: This Image shows the input what I gave]

[image: and this is the data which is being stored]

The data should be `[ABCD, XYZ]`
but it is showing `"[[\"\",\"\"]]"`.

Comment: you have removed the images, also, embed the images directly on the question, do not link them

Comment: thank you for your comment I have updated the image link now please check

Comment: Maybe your localStorage already contains "itemJson"? In that case it wont enter the if-statement. Try to run `localStorage.removeItem('itemsJson')` in your console first.

Comment: @Ivar Thank You for suggestion  , after running `localStorage.removeItem('itemsJson')` I have again entered data and now the data is being stored but those back slash are still there, below is the image https://i.stack.imgur.com/gb5z0.png

Comment: @AbhishekJha What happens if you use `alert()` instead of logging it to the console? I believe those backslashes are added there just for the console because strings in JavaScript can't contain double quotes inside of a string denoted by double quotes. They are not actually part of the string.

Comment: A number of special characters require "escaping" when you write them into a string, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#escape_notation - you see the same kind of escaping in the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The back slashes are supposed to be there.  What you are looking at is a JSON encoded value. They are escaping the double-quotes that are inside the double-quoted string. eg:  `"This \"string\" value contains quotes"`.

JavaScript knows how to build the original data structure from that string (using the values shown from the screenshot in your comments)..

```
var items = localStorage.getItem("itemsJson");  
\\ items[0] value is "s"
\\ items[1] value is "d"
```

I could write the following line of code and get the same result:

```
 var items = "[[\"s\",\"d\"]]";
```

the JSON string value, eg `"[[\"s\",\"d\"]]"`, starts and ends with quotes and the array that is being serialized contains the string values "s" and "d".  If the array contained a number value, eg: 1, as well then the JSON encoded string would look like this:

```
"[[\"s\",\"d\",1]]"
```

If you run the following line of code:

```
alert("This \"string\" value contains quotes");
```

You would see this message: `This "String" value contains quotes`  and illustrates the same concept of what the backslashes are doing.